# duplicate bluetooth devices found. am i double dipping here? also able to update recyclerview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am attempting to build an android application that scans for bluetooth devices and add them to a recyclerview. when i attempt to clear my arraylist and add new data to it in the adapter i end up with an empty arraylist. and when i dont clear the list i end up with a list that contains every device twice like this: `[**:71:9F:B6:59:**, **:71:9F:B6:59:**]` in the logcat. also i think that i am doing something wrong here with my notifydatasetchanged call because nothing is show in my recyclerview at all. i'm sure this is something simple that i am missing but i just can't see it. i am posting the code for my main activity and also my recyclerview.adapter in hopes that someone can point out the problem to me. thanks in advance. here is my main activity:

```
public class ToofActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = "ToofActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 222;

private static BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;

private TextView mStatusLabel;
private Switch mStatusSwitch;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private RecyclerView mDeviceRecylcer;
private static ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices = new ArrayList<>();
private DeviceAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_toof);

    checkLocationPermission();

    btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    mStatusLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_view);
    mStatusSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.status_switch);
    mStatusSwitch.setChecked(btAdapter.isEnabled());
    mStatusSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.search_progress_bar);
    mDeviceRecylcer = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.device_recycler);

    mDeviceRecylcer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(mDevices, getApplicationContext());
    mDeviceRecylcer.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.searchOption:
            DiscoveryTask discovery = new DiscoveryTask(btAdapter, this, mDevices, mProgressBar);
            discovery.setOnCompleteListener(new DiscoveryTask.OnCompletedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "devices found : " + mDevices.toString());
                    mAdapter.updateItems(mDevices);
                }
            });
            discovery.execute((Void) null);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        btAdapter.enable();
        mStatusLabel.setText("Active");
    } else {
        btAdapter.disable();
        mStatusLabel.setText("Inactive");
    }
}

public static void setDeviceList(ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> deviceList) {
    mDevices = deviceList;
}

protected void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0
                    || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                checkLocationPermission();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and also my adapter class which is written in kotlin instead of java:

```
class DeviceAdapter(val mDevices: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>, val mContext : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DeviceAdapter.DeviceHolder>(){

fun updateItems(list: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>){
    //mDevices.clear()
    mDevices.addAll(list)
    Log.d(TAG, "updating items : $mDevices")
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: DeviceHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItems(mDevices.get(position))
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): DeviceHolder?{ //return is not to be NULL!
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.device_item, parent, false)
    return DeviceHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mDevices.size
}

inner class DeviceHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val nameView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameView) as TextView
    val addrView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressView) as TextView

    fun bindItems(btDevice: BluetoothDevice){
        nameView.text = btDevice.name
        addrView.text = btDevice.address
    }
}

companion object {
    val TAG = "DeviceAdapter"
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `DeviceAdapter.mDevices` is the same object as `ToofActivity.mDevices`. So when you clear it, it becomes empty for both, when you `mDevices.addAll(mDevices)`, the elements are doubled.

Remove `mDevices` from the constructor parameters of `DeviceAdapter`.
Create a new `ArrayList` for it in `DeviceAdapter`.